# How Can I Gracefully Handle This Error from my API, and Redirect to my Frontend?

Tags: .net-core

I have a react frontend project that calls a .NET Core API for authentication.  The problem is, I don't know a way to have the auth project redirect to the frontend when it fails *outside of normal http requests*.

When a controller method fails I can return a response that I can handle in my frontend, but when the auth project fails during Startup (say, during AWS authentication) it just returns a 500 error:

```
{"status":500,"message":"An unknown error occurred.","errors":null}
```

How can I configure the project to redirect back to the application by default (hopefully with a helpful error message) when an error occurs at a higher level, as in Program.cs or Startup.cs, so I can present the user with a better experience?